# import public image on Nuxt3 project: Cannot find module '/icon/desktop-solid.svg' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, nuxt3

I import some images(svg, png) from 'public' folder.

these image works fine, they can be shown on the site

only Typescript keeps yelling:

```
Cannot find module '/icon/desktop-solid.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

[image]

I'm not sure if my tsconfig file needs more configuration?

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  // https://v3.nuxtjs.org/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json"
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "nuxt": "^3.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "sass": "^1.62.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.18.0",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.17",
    "nuxi": "^0.10.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "vue": "3.2",
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reasons why you are importing it? You can directly call the svg file path inside the template. 

Comment: lol, now I know the problem is, I can't import image as javascript module, what am I doing??? I probably thought I am writing in next.js framework

Comment: Have same issue, but more complex one, in my case if png imported, build fails with unresolved path error. I suppose, this is an internal VS code error (or its plugins), not Nuxt or Vite, bacause same project works absolutelly normal in WebStorm. Maybe, VSCode cant resolve tsconfig correctly.